# Ventilation for a bathroom

Tags: mold, ventilation

I think a 'mould fix company' is trying to rip me off. They say I have a really wet wall and need to replace the whole wall (inside plaster wall). The bathroom has one small window but is rarely opened as its ground floor and not so private when open.

I found this infrared panel online that I was thinking of trying first - it has good reviews, but do not know if it will actually work.

Also found this fan that says you can't see it from the outside (I live in a building where I need to apply for permission to make a hole so would rather find a solution without that.

Has anyone had similar issues or knowledge to what else I could do?

Comment: The answer below is a very good synopsis of what you need to do.  If that is not possible, you can open the window after you use the bathroom so the humid air can be expelled.

Comment: Zinsser Mildew Proof Interior Paint Satin. - a leaky pipe inside the wall would be a problem, but condensation only ruins the wall board; rarely the structure. So that's patch and paint as necessary... until two foot sections start falling down on their own. - You 'live with it' and paint it once a year.

Answer (score 3):

In most places, every bathroom is required to have at least one of:

- A window that can be opened for ventilation to the outdoors
- An exhaust fan that vents to the outdoors

The primary reason is **humidity**. Excessive humidity over long periods of time is bad for lots of building materials, including drywall, plaster, wood, painted surfaces, etc. Unfortunately, random people on the internet can't determine how extensive your existing problem is, but it is *possible* that you actually need to have walls replaced. It is also *possible* that a company is trying to scam you. Can't tell from here.

The problem is that people *don't* open windows as much as they should, due to:

- Too hot outside
- Too cold outside
- Too noisy outside
- Privacy

which makes an exhaust fan the better choice. However, exhaust fans depend on getting the exhaust out of the building, which means some sort of vent to the outside. If you are in a basement or on the first floor of a building then there are sometimes practical issues - can't have humid air blowing at people walking by. If your bathroom is buried deep within a building then it can be hard to run the necessary ductwork, but then (unless the building is really old) there should ductwork from when it was built. Otherwise, any issues are pretty much cosmetic.

A heater (infrared or any other type) really doesn't solve the problem - it just turns cold water in the air into hot water in the air. A **dehumidifier** can help some, but most that I have seen are designed for long-term use 24 hours a day. Using a dehumidifier for 15 minutes after a bath or shower will not have nearly the same effect as running an exhaust fan for that time, and it will use a lot more energy as well.

So either get used to opening the window or get an exhaust fan installed. I recommend the exhaust fan - a one-time expense (been there, done that) and hassle, but once it is done, you're set for years and don't have to worry about hot/cold/noise/neighbors.